# How to parse datetime based on computer format?

Tags: c#, datetime, globalization

In my website, I use `DateTime.TryParse()` to parse datetime data. My problem is I don't know the format. For example, if the user uses US format, the format would be `mm/dd/yyyy`, while user uses UK, it would use the `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

I think the format is based on their computer settings. So, how can I parse string using the format from their computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" />
<system.web>
```

in `Web.Config` and use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` for getting current culture.

Also you can check `HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages` for getting additional info about client.

Comment: +1 - this is ASP.Net answer (which is probably what OP is looking for - console application will get local culture automatically).

Answer (score 3):

While Frank59's answer is a good start, you should not rely on this exclusively.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) specifically states:

> It is not a best practice to rely exclusively on browser settings to determine the UI culture for a page. Users frequently use browsers that are not set to their preferences (for example, in an Internet cafe). You should provide a method for users to explicitly choose a language or language and culture (CultureInfo name) for the page.

So use `globalization culture="auto"` as a way to set the default culture, but offer your users some sort of dropdown list to override the culture setting.